# What is a rollback operation?

Tags: discussion, editing

What is a rollback operation, what is it used for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038/278094) and the bottom paragraph of the [editing section in the help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing).
Simply put, a rollback reverts an edit (or edits) on a post, returning it to a former state.

To roll a post back:

1. Click the timestamp below the post to view the edit history

   [image: hand drawn arrows showing the location of the timstamp link]
2. Click the "rollback" button next to the revision you wish to revert to.

   [image: post's revision page with the rollback button highlighted]

Comment: UVed for the meta meta, an example image from this post, nice one!

Comment: @gnadalf3 Is there a required reputation to use it? I can't find "last modified" timestamp.

Comment: @Georges Updated answer

Comment: Thanks, I clicked the timestamp, all I get is (source) and (link), no (rollback) or (edit) @gandalf3

Comment: @Georges I can't find it explicitly mentioned anywhere, but perhaps you need [edit privileges](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: Thanks @gandalf3

Comment: @Georges As gandalf already said, you need the edit privilege (2000) to perform a roll back on a post that is not your own and is not a community wiki. For CWs the required rep is 100, and you can always edit your own posts.